# Can I filter a returned JSON by <b> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have been having a bit of a play with this jquery wiki plugin. However I am stuck with a particular function I want to complete. Is there a way to filter the returned data to just show items that are bold or in the `<b>` tag.
I have the following code:

```
<body>
<h1>Wikiblurb</h1>
<div id="article"></div>
<script src="js/jquery.wikiblurb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#article').wikiblurb();
});
</script>
</body>
```

And the main customizing of the .js file is:

```
var defaults = $.extend({
        wikiURL: "http://en.wikipedia.org/",
        apiPath: 'w',
        section: 2,
        page: 'List of reportedly haunted locations',
        removeLinks: true,      
        type: 'all',
        customSelector: '',
        }, options);
```

Has any one used this plugin before or point me in the right direction of how I would only display the locations that returned are within `<b>` tags.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvubbo0s/ 
The intended page for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reportedly_haunted_locations (I only want to return the text of the links under the Australia heading)
The plugin for reference:
https://github.com/9bitStudios/wikiblurb

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you, but reading that Wikipedia article was quite entertaining. Thank you! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugin reference it seems the settings `type: 'custom'` and `customSelector: 'b'` would accomplish what you ask for.

I created a fork of this plugin and added a filterSelector to it to accomplish the last item you asked for. [You can find the forked repository here](https://github.com/plundin/wikiblurb).

In the settings add `filterSelector: "a:contains('^')"`

Comment: ah yes, I seem to have neglected to read that the 'type:' had to be set to custom.

Comment: however, is there a way I can omit the stray '^^^^^^^' present at the end of the string even though they are bold are bold as well.

Comment: thats exactly what I was after. If I was to then send this information as a query through another api, for example google maps. In essence I would just have to use a 'for loop' for each <b> item.